# How to change the text and color of the button on certain event in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, button, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out to change the text and color of the button on certain update to the firestore database. Below is the code which i used for the transaction in adapter. the below code do the work only temporary basis and I want is certain is once done the color and text of the button should be permanently changed.

```
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(likesRef);
        boolean l1 = snapshot.getBoolean("l1");
        if (l1 == false) {

            transaction.update(likesRef, "l1", true);
           // commentsViewHolder.favPostButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
            commentsViewHolder.favPostButton.setText("Let's Chat");

            return l1;
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "You already liked it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            throw new FirebaseFirestoreException("You already liked",
                    FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.ABORTED);
        }
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
        //button change, button appear
      //  commentsViewHolder.favPostButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
      //  commentsViewHolder.favPostButton.setText("Let's Chat");

        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success: " + result);
    }
})
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean through "below code do the work only temporary"?

Comment: i mean to say it changes the text of the button for one session and if i reload the session then it switches back to original text

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the configuration change or activity restart by saying "reload the session"?
Activity is just a dumb pack of UI elements, if you change these during runtime and then reload the app or even just rotate the screen, all the elements are drawn as it is set in your xml layout file or in activity's `onCreate` method.

Activity needs a way to restore its instance.

There are multiple solutions on how to achieve this:
• saving your activity info in `onSaveInstanceState` and reading it in `onCreate`
• using `SharedPreferences`
• observing `LiveData` object